# Certificates, install in local machine before calling a service

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to wrap my head around certificates and any help is appreciated.  So far this is what I understand, please correct me if I am wrong.

1. When using the browser when I navigate to the https site the browser downloads the certificate(without the private key) and then continues to send the data over https?
2. I have come across some sites (especially when developing) that require you to install the certificate on the local machine before making a service call.  What is the purpose here and how does it work?
3. I have also seen some scenarios where you need to install the certificate on the client machine for authentication purposes for example if you are using an email client, how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

> When using the browser when I navigate to the https site the browser downloads the certificate(without the private key) and then continues to send the data over https?

No, the browser and the server stablish a SSL/TLS secure channel with a symmetric encryption key. During the handshake process the server presents the https certificate and digitally signs some data with the private key as a proof of authenticity.

> I have come across some sites (especially when developing) that require you to install the certificate on the local machine before making a service call. What is the purpose here and how does it work?

The client must trust the server certificate. Usually  it has a list with the Certification Authorities for which certificates are accepted. For other certificates is needed to add them to the trust list. If not, the communication will be rejected

> I have also seen some scenarios where you need to install the certificate on the client machine for authentication purposes for example if you are using an email client, how does this work?

Probably the same case as the previous one. Also the public part of the certificate of a user can be used to encrypt a message for him